# How to make pretty url's with scopes using friendly_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm building a blog and I want my categories to have beautiful URL's like
`blog/music`, `blog/art`, etc.

So far, I've managed to make them look like this

`/blog?category=music`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  scope :by_category, -> (slug) { joins(:category).where('categories.slug = ?', slug) if slug }
end
```

-

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders] 
end
```

**view**

```
= active_link_to category.name, articles_path(category: category.slug), remote: true,
     class_active: 'active', class_inactive: 'inactive', wrap_tag: :dd, active: /#{Regexp.escape(category=category.slug)}/
```

**controller**

```
Article.by_category(params[:category])
```

Comment: As I can see, you have overhead. Why you using scope when you can get articles just like that `Category.find(params[:category]).articles` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `friendly_id` only to create slugs based on title of the category. If you want to make slug unique in scope of category you can use special [friendly_id module](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Unique_Slugs_by_Scope) to solve this problem.

To make nice nesting in url you can do something like this in your routes:

```
get 'blog/:category', to: 'articles#index', as: "category"
```

Something like this in your articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category])
    @articles = @category.articles
    respond_to do |format|
      # and so on...
    end
  end
end
```

And something like this in your views:

```
link_to category.title, category_url(category)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `friendly_id` for this task

add something like this to your routes:

```
  get 'blog/:category', to: 'articles#index', as: "category"
```

and then

```
 link_to category, category_path(category)
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Well, `friendly_id` is needed here to create slug based on title of the category ;-)